# sum count and max elastic

Tags: elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

how can i calculate the number of filter : **sum[product.stillDate-Max (product.cutoff)> 0]**

example of given:

**product: A1- consumer: C1**

```
{
"IdProduct": "A1",
"IdConsumer", "C1",
"StillDate": "2017-10-23T10: 00: 00Z"
"Cutoff": "2017-10-21T00: 00: 00Z"
"LibProduct", "test"
}
```

**product: A1- consumer: C2**

```
{
"IdProduct": "A1",
"IdConsumer": "C2"
"StillDate": "2017-10-23T10: 00: 00Z"
"Cutoff": "2017-10-22T08: 00: 00Z"
"LibProduct": "test1"
}
```

**product: A1- consumer: C3**

```
{
"IdProduct": "A1",
"IdConsumer": "C3"
"StillDate": "2017-10-23T10: 00: 00Z"
"Cutoff": "2017-10-23T08: 00: 00Z"
"LibProduct": "test2"
}
```

a product A1 is associated with 3 consumers with 3 cutoffs.

the **maximum** cutoff for product **A1** is:
**2017-10-23T08: 00: 00Z**. So the number is: 
sum ((2017-10-23T10: 00: 00Z -2017-10-23T08: 00: 00Z)> 0) => 1

The question how can I do this on kibana?
Thank you for your help and I apologize for my level in English